# Using execve() to write the ls program in UNIX

Tags: c, unix, exec, argv, ls

At a high level, how would you use the execve() function to write a duplicate of the ls program in UNIX? I am doing an exercise to familiarize myself with the exec() family of functions, command-line arguments, and environment variables. I am not familiar with using these concepts, however I know what they do.

Comment: You wouldn't use exec at all, unless you want to call `ls` to do the work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code below can excute `ls` command. Do you mean this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
        system("ls");
        return 0;
}
```

And I wrote a simple `ls` demo for you.

my_ls.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        if (argc != 2) {
                return 0;
        }

        DIR *dir = opendir(argv[1]);
        if (dir) {
                struct dirent *s_dir;
                while((s_dir = readdir(dir))) {
                        printf("%s ", s_dir->d_name);
                }
                printf("\n");
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Usage:

```
gcc my_ls.c -o my_ls
./my_ls .
```